# Probability - Biased coin

Tags: probability, combinatorics, independence, inclusion-exclusion

A biased coin that comes up heads with probability *p* is flipped *n* times. Let $A_i$ denote the event that the $ith$ flip results in heads (*i* = 1...n)

a) Calculate the probability of $\bigcup_i^nA_i$ by applying De Morgan's Law and then independence of the $A_i$'s

b) Calculate the probability of $\bigcup_i^nA_i$ by applying the inclusion-exclusion principle first then independence of the $A_i$'s

c) By comparing results of the previous parts, prove the identity

$(1-p)^n$ = $\sum_{k=0}^n  {n \choose k} (-1)^kp^k$

for any *n* > 0 and $0\le p\le1$ real number.

d) From the above, prove

$(a-b)^n$ = $\sum_{k=0}^n  {n \choose k} (a)^{n-k} (-b)^k$

for arbitrary positive reals *a* and *b*

PROGRESS:

Ok, so I have for part a) that $\bigcup_i^nA_i$ by De Morgan is equivalent to $(\bigcap_i^nA_i^c)^c$ then by independence we have the probability is $1-(1-p)^n$

For part b) the answer is clearly going to be equivalent to part a) but written in a different form but I am not sure where to go from there. Any help much appreciated!

Comment: How about one question at a time?

Comment: Thought of that but then thought subsequent questions might be unclear as they reference earlier parts of the same question

Comment: Inclusion exclusion is just $P(A\cup B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$.  It generalizes to any finite union as $P(\cup_i A_i) = \sum_i P(A_i)-\sum_{i\neq j} P(A_i\cap A_j)+\sum_{i,j,k} P(A_i\cap A_j\cap A_k)-\dots$
(the sign alternates each time).  What happens if you apply independence ot $P(A_i\cap A_j\cap\dots \cap A_k)$?

After you calculate this, equate it to part c) to get your result for d)

Comment: Even without knowing what inclusion-exclusion is, (see Mark's comment) you could use c) and d) as hint to what b) should be.   As you said, a) and b) should equal, and c) asks you to prove an identity with $(1-p)^n$ on one side, using your answers to a) and b).  Given your answer to a), that's certainly suggestive of what form b) should take.